# Python: Saving Loading Opening and Splitting text files

Tags: python, file, python-3.3

**Problem**
I have a problem. I'm creating a file using `w+` it creates a the text file that i need if it doesn't exist. Then save the file by using `w`. Opens file by using just plain `open("file.txt")`. can someone give it a quick fix please. what am i doing wrong here? thank you so much!

***I get an error when loading the file for some reason it wont allow me to split it so that it becomes a variable.***

***Everything works when i remove the `w+` `from file = open("file.txt", "w+")` in `def player()`. but if the textfile does not exist it wont create a new textfile and the program won't load.***

```
def save():
    file = open("file.txt", "w")
    for i in myList:
    file.write(i) 
    file.write(" ")
    file.write(str(player)) 
    file.write(" ") 
    file.write(str(turn))
    print("Game Saved!") 
def load():
    # it can print the file text but does not print the variables theList, player, turn
    file = open("file.txt")
    for line in file:
    theList, player, turn = line.split(" ")


    print("Game Loaded!")

    if player == "1" and turn == "0" 
# example conditions, this is where i get error saying 
# local variable 'player' referenced before assignment

def superplayer():
    file = open("file.txt", "w+")
    for line in file:
        theList, player, turn = line.split(" ")
# and my code goes on
```

Comment: you are opening a different filename. shouldn't "tic.txt" be "file.txt"? or I misunderstood you?

Comment: sorry.. typo, it is file.txt

Comment: could you post the exact error message and which line is it coming from?

Comment: it's coming from `if player == "1" and turn == "0"`  
`local variable 'player' referenced before assignment`

Comment: I'd check if file.txt actually exist and contains data. if its empty, for example, the loop will never be called and 'player' will never be initialized. you should also open it as "r", it will give error if doesn't exist.

Comment: yes the file.txt exists and it has the right data. i manipulate it and checked multiple times. it prints the contents but for some reason won't assign to variables. it's like IT CANNOT BE ASSIGNED TO A VARRIABLE WHEN THE TEXT FILE WAS CREATED WITH `w+` `w` `a+` `a`. and i don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

Do you ever close the file you open in each method?
A good way to handle files is using with statement:

```
with open('file.txt', 'w+') as file:
    file.seek(0)
    #Do your file handling here
...
```

Have you checked the file for correct info since the player isn't assigned to?

Also try going to the start of the file before reading it with "w+":

```
file.seek(0)
```

Comment: for some reason it is not splitting, and getting the variables when loaded. it is still getting the error even with `with`

Answer (score 0):

You left a colon off on `if player == "1" and  turn == 0`. In addition, try to use the `with` keyword when using files, it's convention and makes things a lot easier for you.

In addition, make sure that `player` at least has a temporary value if the above doesn't fix your problem.

Comment: what do you mean by temporary value? can you revise my code please.

Comment: First of all, indention is required in python. Your `for` block lacks indentation, and that can mess up the entire program.

By temporary value, say that `player = "beep"` or `player = ""`.

Comment: thanks! everything works when i remove the `w+` `from file = open("file.txt", "w+")` in `def player()`. but if the textfile does not exist it wont create a new textfile and the program won't load.

Comment: Try using `a` instead of `w+` maybe? Unless you want to create a new file everytime the program is run.

Comment: can I get a hastebin.com or pastebin.com of your code at this point?

Comment: sure, do you have anything i can send you the file to privately? it's a long code.

Comment: Can you go on chat.stackexchange.com or chat.stackoverflow.com and start a room? I know some methods where you can send it privately.

Comment: can't need 20 rep to chat there

Comment: Oh :[ In that case, can I just have the updated version of the functions showed here?